# PDFNet: How to disable sticky annotations

Tags: c#, winforms, pdftron, pdfnet

When the mouse hovers over an annotation that is not flattened, its icon changes from an arrow to a hand icon.

Since i use a custom cursor for the mouse, i don't want this to happen. I believe this functionality is provided to let the user know he/she can add a sticky annotation to another annotation.

Is there a way to block this functionality?

Comment: Are you using PDFViewCtrl or PDFViewWPF class for viewing?

Comment: i'm using the PDFViewCtrl class

Answer (score 0):

PDFViewCtrl class overrides the OnCursorChanged method. You can subcless PDFViewCtrl, and not call the base class on this call.

For example of overriding the behavior please take a look at the PDFViewTest sample, in particular the OnMouseDown override in MyPDFView.cs file. This is working fine.

Comment: Thank you, will try it out asap

Comment: removing the line "base.OnCursorChanged(e);" in the overriden oncursorchanged method does not work. the cursor still changes